# In how many ways can you pick a group of $5$ people from $13$ people so that Mary and John are not together in the group at the same time?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you pick a group of $5$ people from $13$ people so that Mary and John are not together in the group at the same time?

So, I have these cases:

Mary + $4$ people

John + $4$ people

Group without both Mary and John

First two cases are calculated the same way: $\binom{11}{4}=330$, and third one is $\binom{13}{5} - \binom{11}{3}=1128$

so final solution would be $330 \cdot 2 + 1128$. Is this correct?

Comment: Case III should just be $\binom {11}{5}=462$

Comment: Shouldn't the third term be $\binom{11}{5}$?

Comment: @lulu  right right.. so than final solution would be 462 + 660?

Comment: Yes.  $\quad $ $\quad$.

Comment: Yes, your case (3) counts all of the possible groups - the groups without both mary and john.  That is actually one way to get the answer. But in your answer, you want to count the groups with neither Mary nor John, not the groups that don't contain both mary and john.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\binom{13}{5} - \binom{11}{3} = 1122 $ should be the one step answer by complementary counting. Or $2\binom{11}{4} + \binom{11}{5}$ according to your case work.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $\dbinom{13}{5}$ are all possible choices! The choices where Mary and John are in the same group is $\dbinom{11}{3}$,. So the choices where Mary and John are NOT in the same group is $\dbinom{13}{5}-\dbinom{11}{3}$=$1122$. Therefore I agree with the previous answer! By Mr. Ahala!

Cases where there is only John in the group or only Mary in the group are included in the number $\dbinom{13}{5}$

so there is no point to consider then separately, because it

does not change the result.

The question is clear. How many choices do we have without the pair in the group! A simple much easier example verifying this result. Assume we have 5 people MJABC the cases where MJ are in the same group are MJA,MJB,MJC. The whole mumber of coices are $\dbinom{5}{3}=10$, So the number of choices where MJ are not in the group are 7 which is $\dbinom{5}{3}-\dbinom{3}{1}$=$10-3=7.$